# How to list all the checked-out docs in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using MarkLogic version `8.0-8`

Is there any way to list out the URIS of all the checked-out documents?

Comment: What? Please explain your problem a little better or else we cannot sufficiently help you.

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [DLS](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/dls) Managed Documents, a good start is to use [**`xdmp:document-locks()`**](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-locks).

All checked out DLS documents have a document lock.  If you know the directory where you are managing documents then you can refine the search to that directory.

Note: it is possible to have locks that are not DLS related, so an accurate count should include looking at the result of `xdmp:document-locks` and filtering by either calling or seeing how a call to [`dls:document-checkout-status`](https://docs.marklogic.com/dls:document-checkout-status) is implemented (in dls.xqy)

Comment: Something like this should produce a list of the URIs that have DLS locks: `xdmp:document-locks()/base-uri()[dls:document-checkout-status(.)]`